# T is expansive iff $T^n$ is expansive

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, ergodic-theory

the definition of expansive transformation used is the following:
Let X be a compact metric space and $T: X → X$ a homeomorphism. T is said to be expansive if there exist a $δ > 0$ such that: if
x does not equal y, then there exists an $n ∈ Z$ such that $d(T^n
(x), T^n(y)) > δ.$ $δ$ is called an expansive constant for T.

Here is what I have so far: First for the case where T is expansive, 
I know that since T is a homemorphism then $T^n$ will be one too as composition of hemoemorphism is a homemorphism. Now I tried to use the same $\delta$. Fixing x and y not equal, I need to come up with an m s.t. Definition 7.1.4 Let X be a compact metric space and T : X −→ X a
homeomorphism. T is said to be expansive if there exist a δ > 0 such that: if
x not equal to y then there exists an n ∈ Z such that $d((T^n)^m(x), (T^n)^m(y))>\delta$ 
or $d(T^{nm}(x),T^{nm}(y))>\delta$. However that wont work for all m and n as sometimes nm wont be a multiple of the r required for $T^r(x)$ and $T^r(y)$ to be bigger than $\delta$ apart. Any hints?

Comment: Should the necessary $n$ such that $d(T^n(x), T^n(y)) > \delta$ be strictly positive, or should we also take into account backwards iteration?

Comment: No, n is any integer.

Comment: So there may not exist a positive integer $n$ such that $d(T^n(x), T^n(y)) > \delta$?

Comment: Right there just needs to exist an integer, either positive or negative.

Comment: Or $0$, I assume? Therefore, we only need to take into account $x$ and $y$ that are inside the same ball of radius $\frac{\delta}{2}$.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: $T^0$ is the identity map. For $d(x, y) > \delta$, $d(T^0(x), T^0(y)) > \delta$.

Comment: Yes but I mean how can we only consider balls of radius $\delta/2$

Comment: If there is no closed ball of radius $\delta/2$ containing both $x$ and $y$, then $d(x, y)$ must be larger than $\delta$.

Comment: Oh yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove the easy direction first: if $T^n$ is expansive, then $T$ is expansive. As $T^n$ is expansive, we have some $\delta > 0$ such that $x\neq y$ implies that there exists an $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$d((T^n)^m(x), (T^n)^m(y)) = d(T^{nm}(x), T^{nm}(y)) > \delta$$ Then, as $nm\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have some $n_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d(T^{n_1}(x), T^{n_1}(y)) > \delta$, and so $T$ is expansive. Now, we show that if $T$ is expansive, then $T^n$ is expansive. As $X$ is a compact metric space, $T$ is uniformly continuous. We define $\delta : \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $d(x, y)\leq \delta(\epsilon)$ implies $d(T(x), T(y))\leq \epsilon$. We choose $\delta_1$ as in the condition for $T$ to be expansive. Then, for $x\neq y$, we let $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d(T^m(x), T^m(y)) > \delta_1$. Consider that there is a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $0\leq m-kn\leq n-1$. We let $$\delta_n\leq \min\{\delta_1, \delta(\delta_1), \delta(\delta(\delta_1)), \ldots, \delta^{n-1}(\delta_1)\}$$ Then, as $$d(T^{m-kn}(T^{kn}(x)), T^{m-kn}(T^{kn}(y))) = d(T^m(x), T^m(y)) > \delta_1$$ we cannot have that $$d(T^{kn}(x), T^{kn}(y)) = d((T^n)^k(x), (T^n)^k(y))\leq \delta_n$$ as this would violate the uniform continuity of $T^{m-kn}$ (namely, $\delta_n\leq \delta^{m-kn}(\delta_1)$, so $d(T^{kn}(x), T^{kn}(y))\leq \delta_n$ would imply $d(T^m(x), T^m(y))\leq \delta_1$). Therefore, $\delta_n$ satisfies the condition for $T^n$ to be expansive.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last part though? Why would $d(T^{kn}(x), T^{kn}(y))\leq \delta_n $ imply $d(T^m(x), T^m(y))\leq \delta_1$ ?

Comment: You can see this inductively: as $$d(T^{kn}(x), T^{kn}(y))\leq \delta_n\leq \delta^{m-kn}(\delta_1) = \delta(\delta^{m-kn-1}(\delta_1))$$ we would have $$d(T(T^{kn}(x)), T(T^{kn}(y))) = d(T^{kn+1}(x), T^{kn+1}(y))\leq \delta^{m-kn-1}(\delta_1)$$ Then, $$d(T^{kn+2}(x), T^{kn+2}(y))\leq \delta^{m-kn-2}(\delta_1)$$ Continue this until you have $d(T^m(x), T^m(y))\leq \delta_1$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a bit confused, I'll let it sink in though.

Comment: Perhaps you should choose a specific $n$ and $m$ in order to understand this. For example, try $n = 3$, and let's say that for some chosen $x\neq y$, $d(T^8(x), T^8(y)) > \delta_1$. Then, we have that $d(T^7(x), T^7(y))$ must be greater than $\delta(\delta_1)$ (as otherwise, we would have $d(T^8(x), T^8(y))\leq \delta_1$. Then, we have that $d(T^6(x), T^6(y)) = d((T^3)^2(x), (T^3)^2(y))$ must be greater than $\delta^2(\delta_1)\geq \delta_3$ (as otherwise, we would have $d(T^7(x), T^7(y))\leq \delta(\delta_1)$. We'd have the same steps for any $m$ such that $m\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: There's this inductive process that we can use to go backwards from any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ to some multiple $kn$ of $n$. Since the number of steps in this process is bounded above by $n-1$, we just make $\delta_n$ smaller than all of the necessary $\delta^i(\delta_1)$, $0\leq i\leq n-1$.